# R [ggplot2]: Plot state of boolean variable over time series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame consisting of a date field (POSIXct), a continuous numerical field, and a boolean field.

I have plotted the continuous variable over the date field as a time series.

Now, I want to plot the state of the boolean variable such that intervals over which the boolean variable is TRUE will be highlighted by translucent rectangles. Is there a reasonable way to do this in ggplot2?

See linked image below for example of what I want the plot to look like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfic5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is `geom_tile` with a `height = Inf` argument. If you want the rectangles to start and stop on the x values, instead of being centered on them, you could use something like `geom_tile(aes(x+0.5, y, ...))`. Of course the legend and labels can be modified to your liking.

```
df <- data.frame(y = cumsum(rnorm(30)),
                 x = 1:30,
                 bool = sample(c(T, F), 30, replace = T))

  ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_tile(aes(width = 1, height = Inf, fill = bool), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "blue")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]